# disable kibana default port 5601

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, keycloak

I am working with kibana and keycloak for authentication now a username and password is required for login and this is good but i have a problem that kibana default port still working

Comment: what you mean by default still working ? are you not redirected to keycloak login page if your is not loggedin ?

Comment: i mean that redirect is working but i need to prevent access to this port

Comment: for example i need to redirect to https://ip:8643 or http://ip:8601 i need to prevent access to http://ip:5601

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to update **kibana.yml** configuration file and run Kibana again as follows:

- Stop Kibana if it is running.
- Open **kibana.yml** file located in **../config** directory of your Kibana installation.
- Find the `server.port` line and uncomment it by removing `#` character.
- Replace the default port (5601) with the one you desire (e.g. 8643 or 8601).
- Save the file and run Kibana again.

If you do it properly, you will see an info log message on Kibana console like:

> [16:38:43.437] [info][listening] Server running at
>   http://{IP_Adress}:{new_Port}

From this moment on, nobody can access Kibana through the default "5601" port.